# GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain library licences

Tags: gcc, arm, gnu, libc, libm

I'm developing a commercial software for MCU which is built by GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain. I want to sell the device (product) and I don't want the source code to be released. 
When I compile my code using a `-Wl,--verbose` I see my program uses these libraries:

```
libc, libm, libgcc
```

So my question is: can I use them for my purposes? 
I understand, according to `license.txt`, that `libc` is a `newlib` or `newlib-nano` and I need to be careful, because each part is under different license, right? 
What about other libraries used (`libm, libgcc, libstdc++ , crtend, crtn`, .. ) not covered in `license.txt`, can I use them for my purporses? Under which license are they released?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seeks legal advice.

Comment: For legal advice, you need to ask a lawyer. Also, the answer may depend on whether you are linking against these libraries statically or dynamically.